# How to correctly set async recursion in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Here is one example function.

```
async function getRandomBig() {
    let result;
    result = await randomModule.getRandom();
    if (result > 0.9 ) {
        return getRandomBig();
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

So Obviously, I would like that execution to `randomModule.getRandom()` happens asynchronously. Is this example the way to go?

Also, I would like to know how to make the first call to getOutput be asynchronous.

Thank you

Comment: entirely depends on the code in `randomModule.getRandom`

Comment: Thank you, let's say I create Math.random() inside that module, how to return the value asynchronously?

Comment: And also, is it possible to call getRandom() asynchronously even though the code gets executed synchronously?

Comment: you can wrap it by a promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to answer your question given the info you've provided, but maybe this will help:

The async function will return a promise to the outside caller. Than means that results obtained from `await` will happen asynchronously. For example consider this code:

```js
// normal synchronous function
function changeRes() {
  return "after"
}

// sync function that `awaits` it's result
async function getget() {
  res = await changeRes()
}

let res = "before"

// p will be a pending promise
var p = getget()

// what is res at this point?
console.log(res) // still "before" because await doesn't return until next tick

// now res is 'after'
p.then(() => console.log(res))
```

But be careful because the call to `changeRes` is not asynchronous — it is called in the current loop. Compare this with the first code. We only change the behavior of `changeRes()`:

```js
function changeRes() {
  res = "after"
  return res
}
async function getget() {
  res = await changeRes()
}
let res = "before"

// p is still a pending promise
var p = getget()

// but res was changed in changeRes synchronously
console.log(res)

p.then(() => console.log(res))
```

**EDIT based on comment:**

With the recursive function, everything important is happening inside the async function, so it all should work as expected. For example, you can substitute your `randomModule.getRandom` with the regular `Math.random()` which is synchronous, but the `await` will make it work in the context of an async function. So this function will return a promise that resolves to a random float less than 0.25:

```js
async function getRandomBig() {
  let result;
  result = await Math.random();
  if (result > 0.25) {
    return getRandomBig();
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}

getRandomBig().then(console.log)
```

So will this even though it's truly async:

```js
function asyncRandom(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), 500)
    })
}
async function getRandomBig() {
    let result;
    result = await asyncRandom();
    if (result > 0.25 ) {
        console.log("too big recurse")
        return getRandomBig();
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
getRandomBig().then(console.log)
```

Comment: I just saw that I had a typo in my question, can you update your question to reflect the recursion? thank you

Comment: Also to clarify, the function is called synchronously but the result is saved to the variable after the next tick, and than it continues

Comment: Great! Thank you. I really understand it now.